# I am getting type error while using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to tune `n_estimators` of `RandomForestClassifier` using `GridSearchCV`. But I am getting type error saying -> `TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Code:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

n_trees = list(range(10,110,10))
print(n_trees)

[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

param_grid = dict(n_estimators=n_trees)
print(param_grid)

{'n_estimators': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}

grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')


grid.fit(X,y)   <--- Getting error at this cell
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: You need to pass the classifier not the base class as the estimator. So add the `()`  to the base class i.e  `RandomForestClassifier()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line `grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')`, instead of what you've written, try
`grid = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')`

I can't say for sure.. Because you're not giving me `X` and `y`, or I could be able to reproduce it in my laptop and let you know if it works!

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I will let you know in 5min because now `grid.fit(X,y)` is running and will take time :)